# Site working in VS Code but not on actual website

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-code

I'm relatively new to coding, but I'm trying to use the below element on my website.  It works flawlessly when using localhost on VS Code but when I upload this to my site, the style is all messed up and it looks like the script is also not working.  I've been trying to fix this for days and I am getting nowhere.  Can someone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   </head>

<body>

  <style>
      .countries-container .profile {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
    background-color: #4D4D4D;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  }
  .material-card {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: calc(100% - 16px);
    margin-bottom: 4.7em;
  }
  .material-card h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% - 16px);
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .material-card h2 span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
  .material-card h2 strong {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.7em;
  }
  
  .material-card.mc-active h2 {
    top: 0;
    padding: 10px 16px 10px 70px;
  }

  .material-card.mc-active h2:before {
    top: 0;
  }
  .material-card.mc-active h2:after {
    bottom: 0px;
  }
  .material-card .mc-content {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .material-card .mc-btn-action {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 15px;
    width: 54px;
    height: 54px;
    line-height: 44px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 20;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .material-card.mc-active .mc-btn-action {
    top: 290px;

  }
  .material-card .mc-description {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    color: white;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition: all 1.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 1.2s;
    -o-transition: all 1.2s;
    transition: all 1.2s;
  }
  
  .material-card .img-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .material-card.mc-active .img-container {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 12px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 20;
  }
  .material-card.mc-active .mc-content {
    padding-top: 5.6em;
    height: 345px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .material-card.mc-active .mc-description {
    top: 25px;
    padding-top: 5.6em;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .material-card.prof1 h2 {
    background-color: #ff9800;
  }
  .material-card.prof2 h2 {
    background-color: #001523;
  }
  .material-card.prof3 h2 {
    background-color: #ff9800;
  }
  body {
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'D2DBody2';
    min-height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body > * {
    width: 100%;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h7 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 35pt;
    color: black;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1.3px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
    font-family: 'D2DTitle2', sans-serif;
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'D2DTitle2', sans-serif;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'D2DTitle2', sans-serif;}

h4 {
    font-size: 11pt;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'D2DBody1';

}

h5 {
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: 'D2DBody1';
}

h6 {
        font-size: 10pt;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'D2DBody1';
    }
    .container {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.countries-container {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
  }

  </style>
   
    <div id="countries" class="countries-container container">
      <div class="profile">
    <article class="material-card prof1">
      <h2>
          <span>Profile 1</span>
          <strong>
              Title
          </strong>
      </h2>
      <div class="mc-content">
          <div class="img-container">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://material-cards.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumb-christopher-walken.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="mc-description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et massa at urna eleifend eleifend vel vel lacus. Praesent nec malesuada sapien. Quisque ut commodo ligula. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam non ante tortor. Sed eget eros eu turpis ullamcorper varius at et ipsum. Pellentesque eu pretium arcu.
                    </div>
      </div>
      <a class="mc-btn-action">
          <img style="width:70%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Blue_circle_logo.svg/350px-Blue_circle_logo.svg.png">
      </a>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="profile">
  <article class="material-card prof2">
    <h2>
        <span>Profile 2</span>
        <strong>
            Title
        </strong>
    </h2>
    <div class="mc-content">
        <div class="img-container">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://material-cards.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumb-christopher-walken.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="mc-description">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et massa at urna eleifend eleifend vel vel lacus. Praesent nec malesuada sapien. Quisque ut commodo ligula. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam non ante tortor. Sed eget eros eu turpis ullamcorper varius at et ipsum. Pellentesque eu pretium arcu.
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="mc-btn-action">
        <img style="width:70%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Blue_circle_logo.svg/350px-Blue_circle_logo.svg.png">
    </a>
</article>
</div>

<div class="profile">
  <article class="material-card prof3">
    <h2>
        <span>Profile 3</span>
        <strong>
            Title
        </strong>
    </h2>
    <div class="mc-content">
        <div class="img-container">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://material-cards.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumb-christopher-walken.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="mc-description">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et massa at urna eleifend eleifend vel vel lacus. Praesent nec malesuada sapien. Quisque ut commodo ligula. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam non ante tortor. Sed eget eros eu turpis ullamcorper varius at et ipsum. Pellentesque eu pretium arcu.
                  </div>
    </div>
    <a class="mc-btn-action">
        <img style="width:70%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Blue_circle_logo.svg/350px-Blue_circle_logo.svg.png">
    </a>
</article>
</div>

</div>

  
<script>
    $(function() {
            $('.material-card > .mc-btn-action').click(function () {
                var card = $(this).parent('.material-card');
                var icon = $(this).children('i');
                icon.addClass('fa-spin-fast');
    
                if (card.hasClass('mc-active')) {
                    card.removeClass('mc-active');
    
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        icon
                            .removeClass('fa-arrow-left')
                            .removeClass('fa-spin-fast')
                            .addClass('fa-bars');
    
                    }, 800);
                } else {
                    card.addClass('mc-active');
    
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        icon
                            .removeClass('fa-bars')
                            .removeClass('fa-spin-fast')
                            .addClass('fa-arrow-left');
    
                    }, 800);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any messages in the browser developer tools?

Comment: Maybe somehow vsc reads it and makes it work but shouldn't <style> tag be inside <head>?